# Help me fix these crazy attachment page URLs (rewrite?)

Tags: permalinks, attachments

On one of my sites if a post's permalink is as follows:

```
http://example.com/side-view-of-sheikh-zayed-grand-mosque-in-abu-dhabi-united-arab-emirates/
```

the attachment page for the thumbnail image (i.e. featured image) will be like this:

```
http://example.com/side-view-of-sheikh-zayed-grand-mosque-in-abu-dhabi-united-arab-emirates/side-view-of-sheikh-zayed-grand-mosque-in-abu-dhabi-united-arab-emirates-2/
```

In other words, the attachment page URL is a repetition of the parent post's URL (sometimes with a '2' slapped on it at the end like in the example).

I want to make the attachment page URLs like this:

```
http://example.com/post-url/artwork-detail/
```

I also pass GET parameters to the attachment pages like this:

```
http://example.com/post-url/post-url?size=400
```

I want this to become:

```
http://example.com/post-url/artwork-detail/size-400
```

The URL duplication is my big concern, the GET translation isn't a priority so long as the parameters aren't lost.

Answer (score 1):

The attachment page generally gets the "title" value as it's slug. Are you not filling in the image information like title, caption, etc? Might give that a try.

Comment: Ah thank you! I realize that this is the issue. I have code that grabs the parent post's title and uses it as the image title (which is then used to rename the image file). In this case I will change my code to work on another image attribute to avoid this duplication.